# MySQL optimization - use of index

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I have the following INDEX on table a:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM a
```

> Table, Non_unique, Key_name, Seq_in_index, Column_name, Collation, Cardinality, Sub_part, Packed, Null, Index_type, Comment, Index_comment
>
> a, '1', 'oc_id', '1', 'OC_ID', 'A', '19', NULL, NULL, 'YES', 'BTREE', '', ''

And the `explain` plan shows it's being used:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM a
WHERE OC_ID IN (
                5841)

'1', 'SIMPLE', a, 'ref', 'oc_id,oc1', 'oc_id', '6', 'const', '121080', 'Using where'
```

But using a subquery it's not used:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM a
WHERE OC_ID IN (SELECT OC_ID FROM b WHERE tteci = "54301")

'1', 'PRIMARY', a, 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '701145408', 'Using where'
'2', 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', b, 'index_subquery', 'OC_ID,tteci1', 'OC_ID', '6', 'func', '1', 'Using where'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first step is to *eliminate the subquery* by replacing it with a join (hint: join `a` and `b` on OC_ID and filter `b` on tteci). Then either 1) MySQL will "be happy" and select the desired index, or 2) the question will be different as the subquery is no longer relevant / existing.

Comment: Something does not make sense; _please_ provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for better performance you could use a join instead of an IN clause  based on a subselect result

```
SELECT * 
FROM a
INNER  JOIN b ON a.OC_ID = b.OC_ID and b.tteci =  "54301"
```

for index  you should use an composite one with the columns involved in the JOIN clause  eg for table b :

```
(tteci, OC_ID)
```

for table a the OC_ID index is enough

Comment: (Newer versions of MySQL will do this sort of rewrite for you _in some cases_.)

Comment: I don't know the version  use by the OP  ..  but an IN clause  with a subselect should be avoided  in every case  ..